# MS Access automatically fill Query column based on start and end date

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a Query called `Records Query` which I'm entering the information with a form.

Every record has a date.

In another table I have a list of date ranges with the name of the range. That means the first column is the `Range name`, the second `Start date` and the third, `End date`.

I want the last column on the `Records Query` to show the name of the date range that that specific range is in.

For example, if I have the following date ranges:

```
+------------+----------+----------+
| Start date | End date |   Name   |
+------------+----------+----------+
| Jan 1      | Jan 10   | session1 |
| Jan 11     | Jan 20   | session2 |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

If the date of that record in `Records Query` is Jan 2, the value of column `Session` should automatically be `session1`

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dates are stored using `DateTime` fields and that your date ranges are contiguous (no gaps), you can determine the appropriate session name for your date using the following correlated subquery:

```
SELECT q.*,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 r.Name 
    FROM Ranges r 
    WHERE q.MyDate <= r.[End date] ORDER BY r.[End date]
) AS SessionName
FROM [Records Query] q
```

Here, I assume that your date ranges are stored in a table called `Ranges` and that the date field in your `Records Query` query is called `MyDate` (change this to suit your data).

In the above example, I'm assuming you have the following setup:

#### Ranges

[image: Ranges]

#### Records Query

[image: Records Query]

#### SQL

[image: SQL]

#### Result

[image: Result]

Unfortunately, you cannot simply inject this subquery into an `UPDATE` query -

```
UPDATE [Records Query] q
SET q.Session = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 r.Name 
    FROM Ranges r 
    WHERE q.MyDate <= r.[End date] ORDER BY r.[End date]
)
```

...as the resulting query will not be updateable (as the new value references the table being updated).

As such, you will likely need to output the session names to and primary key from your `Records Query` query to a local table which can then be used to update your query - others may hopefully know a more elegant way to avoid this.

Comment: For some reason it still dosen't say the session name, in the session column

Comment: @Allan Are you saying that the `SessionName` field of my first SQL statement is empty?

Comment: Yes. Really not sure why, I double and triple checked to make sure i dident make a mistake

Comment: @Allan Did you change `MyDate` in my code to the name of your date field in `Records Query` as instructed?

Answer (score 1):

You can join by a simple Where clause:

```
Select
     [Records Query].*,
     [Date Ranges].[Name] As [Session Name]
From
     [Records Query],
     [Date Ranges]
Where
     [Records Query].[Date] Between [Date Ranges].[Start date] And [Date Ranges].[End date]
```

Comment: Sorry i'm a bit new. Where do i type this

Comment: Open a new query, switch to SQL view, paste code. Of course, change names of table/query and fields to those of yours.

Comment: I tried this, but the value in the Session Name column does not say the session name. The only thing it does is filters the records based on the last session

Comment: Then you probably have mistyped something and/or the dates fits that session only. We have neither your data nor your query, so it is not easy to be more specific.